# How to use _PARTITIONTIME with Simba's BigQuery JDBC Driver?

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, simba

Is there any way to list the _PARTITIONTIME field while using the JDBC provided by Simba/Google?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/

I could not find any information regarding this in their documentation.
Found these links:

http://cdn.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/Simba_BigQuery_ODBC_JDBC_Datasheet.pdf
https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/d-intro.htm
http://cdn.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/Simba_BigQuery_ODBC_JDBC_Datasheet.pdf

Also, there are nothing related to the AutoCommit capabilities. I've tried to use it without autocommit disabled and looks like it is not possible, and if I create the connection (I am using Datagrip), set the default to manual, open a console and set that specific console to Auto, gives me an error.

*Edit1 - 01/29/2018*

I am getting this error when I try to query with AutoCommit disabled. I've setup the connection using Datagrip:

[Datagrip BigQuery JDBC error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjCj9.png)

Comment: What error are you getting? JDBC should be agnostic to the query

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I've updated my question with the error screenshot